# How can I understand the mean of convoluted Gaussian function is $\mu_1 + \mu_2$.

Tags: gaussian-integral

I struggle to understand the mean of convoluted two Gaussian functions is $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ instead of $(\mu_1 + \mu_2)/2$. Could someone provide visual explaination?

Comment: Can you explain in your question why you think it should be halved? Do you understand that if $X$ and $Y$ have distributions $f$ and $g$ then $X + Y$ has distribution $f * g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two *independent* continuous random variables with means $E[X]=\mu_X$ and $E[Y] = \mu_Y$, then the density of their sum $X+Y$ is the *convolution* of the densities of $X$ and $Y$.  In the special case when $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables, $X+Y$ is also a Gaussian random variable.  But, regardless of whether $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian or not, independent or not, or continuous or not, it is true that
$$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y].$$
This result is referred to as the *linearity of expectation*, and explains why the mean of $X+Y$ is $\mu_X + \mu_Y$, and not the arithmetic average $\frac{\mu_X+\mu_Y}{2}$ that you are hoping to see.

*Visually*, the densities of independent Gaussian $X$ and $Y$ are bell-shaped curves centered at $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ respectively, and the value of the convolution of these densities at $z$ (a.k.a the numerical value of the density of $X+Y$ at $z$) is obtained by

- "flipping" the density of $Y$ about the origin the result of which operation looks for all the world just like the density of $Y$ centered at $-\mu_Y$ instead of at $\mu_Y$.
- sliding the flipped density to the right by $z$
- multiplying the density of $X$ with the flipped and slid density of $Y$ *and* integrating the product from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

If your brain has not already boggled at all these shenanigans and can still visualize a tad more, consider that the maximum value of the integral will occur when the two peaks align, that is, when the flipped density of $Y$ has been slid so that its peak at $-\mu_Y$ has shifted due to the slide so that it coincides with the peak of the $X$ density which is at $\mu_X$, i.e. a total slide of $\mu_X+\mu_Y$.  So, the peak of the convolution is at $\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and so the mean of $X+Y$ is $\mu_X+\mu_Y$.